# Is a Mann-Whitney Test Appropriate for This Data?

Tags: nonparametric, bootstrap, independence, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

So my sample is 500 and split in two groups.

The data is the distance in minutes to the nearest supermarket. There were 500 respondents in total and broken down into two groups (male and female). I want to compare is for significant difference.

Group 1 = n= 210 
Group 2 = n= 290

I have checked and it looks like the data is positively skewed. I assume this means I need to use a non-parametric test?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your null hypothesis. The original Mann - Whitney (MW) $H_0$ hypothesis is that "the probability of an observation from the population X exceeding an observation from the second population Y equals the probability of an observation from Y exceeding an observation from X", that is $H_0: Pr\left(Y>X\right) = Pr\left(X>y\right)$. If you want to test this assumption the MW test is appropriate whichever the underlying distribution is since it does not hold any distribution assumpotion.

Btw, MW test is often used as a nonparametric alternative to Two Sample T-test, that tests whether the means of the two groups are statistically different. In such case, taking into account the relatively high sample size of the two samples an independent sample T-Test is appropriate since the central theorem limit assumptions are likely met (consensus is on 50 observation by groups). 
An advantage of using the T Test instead of the MW one is that more power is granted.